# Combining Angular Services with NodeJS Modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Supposing I have a library written in Javascript to be used in a MEAN stack application.

I wish to use my library both from NodeJS and within Angular.
To remain idiomatic I would like the library to appear as a Module inside node and as a Service within Angular.

the only way I can think to do this is to do something like:

```
var myLibrary = function(){
    var myLib = {};
    myLib.myFunc1 = function() {
        //Do some cool stuff
    };
    return myLib;        
};    

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = myLibrary();
} else{
    var app = angular.module('myApp.services', []);
    app.factory('myLibrary',myLibrary);
}
```

This will work, but it has at least two significant limitations:

- The namespace is polluted with the variable "myLibrary"
- If within the library I want to use other node modules or Angular services then I can't

I would like to know if anyone knows of a better solution, or if I should give up on using Angular services and use one of the libraries that allows client side Node module functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Having done a bit of searching about this looks like the best solution:

https://gist.github.com/sevcsik/9207267